# Using VB locate an IP address within an XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, ip

New to VB scripting, I am looking to perform upgrades to Symantec. However to do this I need to look at the sylink.xml file for a specific IP. If it exist, I can do the upgrade. I tried to treat it as a text file and I wasn't even able to read a test text file I created with just the IP in it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.  Also, since it's an XML file, I would suggest using LINQ to XML - Google will give plenty of examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy was to load the `xml` file. Once you know the element name to search for it is pretty easy. In my example the ipaddress is in the element named `ipAdress`.

```
Dim x As XElement = XElement.Parse({xml string})
Dim ip As String = x...<ipAdress>.FirstOrDefault.Value
```